# No Python at "...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'

Tags: python, windows

I installed Python 3.11 using the Windows Store and wanted to use Python 3.10 instead. So I uninstalled Python 3.11 and installed 3.10.

Running `python --version` gives the correct output `"Python 3.10.11"`, but when I'm trying to run a `.bat` file that uses Python, it spits out:

```
No Python at "...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
```

I figured it was possible that it was lingering in the PATH somewhere, but I didn't see it there either.

The `.bat` file is `webui.bat` from https://github.com/vladmandic/automatic.

Comment: How, exactly, did you run the bat file?

Comment: And can you post the first few lines of the bat file

Comment: The `.bat` file is `webui.bat` from https://github.com/vladmandic/automatic. Just running the bat file in terminal, `./webui.bat`

Comment: Never mind, solved it. Deleted `venv` folder and reinstalled.

Comment: Deleting the repo folder and cloning the repo again solved it for me too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the .bat file to use the correct Python executable path for Python 3.10.

1. Open the webui.bat file in your IDE or text editor.
2. Locate the line that sets the PYTHON variable (line 3). It should look like this:

   > **if not defined PYTHON (set PYTHON=python)**
3. Replace the line with the following code:

   > **if not defined PYTHON (set PYTHON=C:\Path_To\Python3.10\python.exe)**
4. Replace "C:\Path_To\Python3.10" with the actual installation path of Python 3.10 on your system.
5. Save the modified webui.bat file.